# Resolution independent UNet implementation?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I'm wondering what's the easiest way to make a UNet model work with varying input resolutions? What I mean is that if I downsample 3 times, then with e.g. a 320x320 size image the spatial dimensions of feature layers will be:

```
320 -> 160 -> 80 -> 40 -> 80 -> 160 -> 320
```

On the other hand, if I input an image of size, say, 960x540, then I get

```
540 -> 270 -> 135(!) -> 68 -> 136(!) ->...
```

The network will blow up with such an input image, because the tensor sizes have a mismatch when concatenating the tensor from the skip.

Is there some standard trick for handling this?

Comment: You can resize the input image to the nearest multiple of 8 (while maintaining the aspect ratio). In such a case, dividing by 2 three times will have integer output every time. Might not be a standard trick, but it should work.

Comment: Yeah, I guess if I choose e.g. reflection padding of the input and then remove that from the output, then it should work OK.

Comment: I meant resize using something like opencv's `cv2.resize` function. So, it will resize the image using bilinear interpolation I think. So, your image looks like the original one, just the size changes.

Comment: That won't work on images that are highly rectangular, since the change in aspect ratio will e.g. prevent the network from recognizing common objects. However, padding to a size that can handle the downsampling (i.e. make dimensions divisible with the right numbers) and then removing the padding from the output seems to work.